# Notation for where two variables cannot both simultaneously take a specific value

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I am building a set of values A, containing coordinates ($B_{x,y}$), where $x$ and $y$ take any of the following values:

$x$ := {-2,-1,0,1,2} and $y$ := {-1,0,1}

The catch is that both $x$ and $y$ cannot both simultaneously equal 0. Is there a notation for this? I've written the following, but don't know if it's correct...

A := {$B_{x,y}$}, where $x$ = $y$ $\not=$ 0, and where $x$ := {-2,-1,0,1,2}, $y$ := {-1,0,1}

Comment: You could write $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$. Also, it should be $x\in\{\ldots\}$, not $x:=\{\ldots\}$.

Comment: Writing $x = y \neq 0$ should be avoided, as it suggests that $x$ should equal $y.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not correct to right $x := ...$ as this is read "*x* is defined to be..."
rather, you can write it a number of ways:

$$
x \in \{-2,-1,0,1,2\},~~~ y \in \{-1,0,1\}\\
A = \{~B_{(x,y)}~|~ (x,y) \neq (0,0) ~\}
$$

or more compactly, 
$$
A = \{~B_{(x,y)}~|~ (x,y) \neq (0,0),~x \in \{-2,-1,0,1,2\},~ y \in \{-1,0,1\}~\}
$$

or even use the Cartesian product,
$$
A = \{~B_{c}~|~ c \in \{\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}  \times\{-1,0,1\}\}\backslash(0,0)~ \}
$$

Answer (score 2):

You could write $A = \{B_{x,y}\}$ with $(x,y)\in \{-2,1,0,1,2\}\times\{-1,0,1\}\setminus\{(0,0)\}$.

Otherwise I think you should just say "both $x$ and $y$ cannot be zero". I'm divided as to which is clearer.

Comment: if there's no simpler correct way of writing it, then text might be clearer as you suggested - thanks